# using @property encapsulation in ios

Tags: ios

I'm confused in way of using @property in lot of sites, is there any difference between following codes..

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject
    @property NSString *firstName;
    @property NSString *lastName;
@end
```

and

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject {
    @property NSString *firstName;
    @property NSString *lastName;
} @end
```

and

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject {
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName, *lastName;
@end
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first one declares properties without specifying attributes. So you don't get copy semantics and the accessors are atomic.
- The second one is illegal. Only instance variables can go in the curly braces.
- The third one declares properties and specifies attributes (nonatomic, copy), and also declares backing instance variables explicitly (pointlessly, since backing instance variables will be autosynthesized and they won't be these instance variables).

And none of them is right. If these are public properties, you should say:

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;
@end
```

You always want copy semantics on a public NSString property so no one can slip you an NSMutableString and mutate your property behind your back. And you should always specify `nonatomic` unless you're multithreaded.

Comment: Oh come on. It won't _compile_.

Comment: But I mean did you even _try_ these? What's the point of your question? Is it supposed to be some kind of intelligence test or are you really trying to find out something? If so, what?

Comment: I'm new on IOS, And I'm confused in way of using @property in lot of sites.. That's why bro.. Thanks..

Comment: Then you should have asked about that. Or maybe, like, done some research. Just throwing stuff at the wall and saying "what's the difference" is no way to ask a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: If you're actually trying to learn something, and not just yanking our chain, my explanation of property declarations is here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_properties_2

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are differences. The first one is correct. The second one won't even compile, and the third one will give you warnings (in the .m file) saying that the property will use the auto synthesized ivars _firstName and _lastName instead of the ivars you created.